# Função calculo de mês

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função que identifica o mês mediante a duas entradas, a de mês inicial e também a de diferença que seria o alcance máximo do meu array. Ao mesmo tempo existe outra condição que no caso, limita minha lista a 6 valores

```
var CountMes = 0;
function DataTabela(mesInicial, Diferenca) {
    var Meses = [];
    Meses.push(mesInicial);
    while (CountMes < 5 && Diferenca > CountMes) {
        CountMes++;
        mesInicial++;
        Meses.push(mesInicial);
    }
    alert(Meses.toString());
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente enquanto estamos no mesmo ano. Meu problema é, se a minha entrada de mês inicial for 11 (novembro) e minha diferença for 4, minha lista deveria possuir: novembro, dezembro,janeiro e fevereiro. Porém, como a conta é em base 12 e janeiro seria equivalente a `mesInicial = 1`, como posso modelar minha função para ela ser adaptvel para transições de ano?

Comment: Já pensou em trabalhar com um *array* contendo inteiros de 1 a 12 e reiniciar a busca nesse *array* caso o calculo de entrada e diferença ultrapasse 12?

Comment: Tipo, você encotra a posição da entrada no array e daí avança as casa de acordo com a diferença, reiniciando a busca no array se passar de 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var CountMes = 0;
function DataTabela(mesInicial, Diferenca) {
    var Meses = [];
    Meses.push(mesInicial);
    while (CountMes < 5 && Diferenca > CountMes) {
        CountMes++;
        mesInicial++;
        //////
        if ( mesInicial > 12 ) mesInicial = 1;
        //////
        Meses.push(mesInicial);
    }
    alert(Meses.toString());
}
```

Poderia pensar em outra lógica mais compacta:

```
function DataTabela( mesInicial, Diferenca ) {
   var Meses = [];
   for ( i = 0; i < 5 && i < Diferenca; i++ ) {
      Meses.push( ( ( mesInicial + i - 1 ) % 12 ) + 1 );
   }
   alert(Meses.toString());
}
```

Nota: o % é o [operador de módulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) (ou de "resto").

Comment: É, isso ficou melhor que o que minha sugestão.

Comment: @ErlonCharles veja a segunda parte :)

Comment: Valeu pela moral :D